# how to make a better curve fit while focusin on some better accuracy

Tags: python, curve-fitting, data-fitting

the past two days I have been working on a specific data fit (orange line of  picture [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPzxs.png) ).

Thing is, I want it to be accurate on the bigger θ[0.1,1]. As a matter of fact, I wanted to start at the same point (so for `θ=1` we got `ψ=1` too) with this form:

`ψ_f=a1*(1-x)**a2 +a3*(1-x)**a4+1`

but it was super bad as it gets on `inf` for bigger `θ`.

For the image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPzxs.png) I used 
`scipy.optimize.curve_fit`
 for a simple form

`ψ_f = a1 *x**a2`

Αny other form was flat bad.

Any idea what to do? :(

EDIT:

Data is form [this file](https://ufile.io/pu4pv) using following loading code:

```
ww=np.load('Hot3.npy')
s=ww[3]
z=np.array([ww[0],ww[1],ww[2])
```

and the `xdata,ydata` is equal to

```
xdata = s/max(s)
ydata = z[2]/min(z[2])
```

[image: Orange is datafit]

Comment: Is this a programming question or a maths question?

Comment: Please post a link to the data.

Comment: @JamesPhillips Just did. It's a file though, and a .npy one so I had to upload it. Also added the loadin and the xdata and ydata code part

Comment: @wwii I don't know if there is some routine allowing to to enter a better percision for a ceratin aera(programming), or there is just a better function for this curve(maths). Have been searching past days and  thought I should ask here..

Comment: @JamesPhillips Did I make something wrong? :(

Comment: I'm not sure yet.

Comment: Ok, if there is no way to solve then i should just leave it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some example code that appears to give a better fit. Note that I have not taken any logs, nor plotted on a log scale.
[image: plot]

```
import numpy, scipy, matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import warnings


ww=numpy.load('/home/zunzun/temp/hot3.npy')
xData = ww[3]/max(ww[3])
yData = ww[2]/min(ww[2])


def func(x, a, b, c): # Combined Power And Exponential equation from zunzun.com
    power = numpy.power(x, b)
    exponent = numpy.exp(c * x)
    return a * power * exponent 


# numpy defaults are all 1.0, try these instead
initialParameters = numpy.array([1.0,-1.0,-1.0])

# ignore intermediate overflow warning during curve_fit() routine
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

# curve fit the test data
fittedParameters, pcov = curve_fit(func, xData, yData, initialParameters)

modelPredictions = func(xData, *fittedParameters) 

absError = modelPredictions - yData

SE = numpy.square(absError) # squared errors
MSE = numpy.mean(SE) # mean squared errors
RMSE = numpy.sqrt(MSE) # Root Mean Squared Error, RMSE
Rsquared = 1.0 - (numpy.var(absError) / numpy.var(yData))

print('Parameters:', fittedParameters)
print('RMSE:', RMSE)
print('R-squared:', Rsquared)

print()


##########################################################
# graphics output section
def ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)
    axes = f.add_subplot(111)

    # first the raw data as a scatter plot
    axes.plot(xData, yData,  'o')

    # create data for the fitted equation plot
    xModel = numpy.linspace(min(xData), max(xData))
    yModel = func(xModel, *fittedParameters)

    # now the model as a line plot
    axes.plot(xModel, yModel)

    axes.set_xlabel('X Data') # X axis data label
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data') # Y axis data label

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot

graphWidth = 800
graphHeight = 600
ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight)
```

Comment: The Log-Log scale was even worse this way :(

Comment: Perhaps instead of a single equation, you could model the "vertical" data and the "horizontal" data using two separate equations with some data overlap in the region where they join. Would such a model be useful for your purpose?

Comment: What? I have found some medicore fit with the use of a*(x/b)**c +d form. Thanks tho!